# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am using a code for fetching no. of hits of a particular phrase for implementing Semantic Orientation.

```
def hits(word1,word2=""):
query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%s"
if word2 == "":
    results = urllib.urlopen(query % word1)
else:
    results = urllib.urlopen(query % word1+" "+"AROUND(10)"+" "+word2)
json_res = json.loads(results.read())
google_hits=int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
return google_hits
```

but when I am giving a long file containing phrases it executes upto some extent but return Error

```
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "
```

the error is dynamic as it sometimes executes some phrases and sometimes not. I think its a problem of google API which I am using.  This function calculates SO using above .

```
def so(phrase):
num = hits(phrase,"excellent")
print num
den = hits(phrase,"poor")
print den
ratio = (num/ den+0.01)*0.6403669724770642
print ratio
sop = log(ratio)
return sop
```

Anyone has idea please help !!!

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate the error with the following line of code:

```
None["key"]
```

The error is telling you that one of the levels of:

```
json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']
```

`is None`. You need to check that the data you receive is what you expect. For example, as a minimal change:

```
try:
    google_hits=int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
except TypeError:
    print query
    print json_res
    google_hits = 0
```

Also, your mix of old-style `%` string formatting and `+` string concatenation should be replaced with `str.format`:

```
query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={0}"
payload = "{0} AROUND(10) {1}".format(word1, word2) if word2 else word1
results = urllib.urlopen(query.format(payload))
```

Comment: The code really works brother !!! but again i am facing the same problem i think its due to the Google API i am using . After a certain no. of hits returned its blocked and does not return any result and its gives a error message [http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={0}
{u'responseData': None, u'responseDetails': u'Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors', u'responseStatus': 403}]  

If there is any chance of using another API to calculate the HITS of phrase. if any idea please help